How can I monitor query performance on my Azure read-replica database?
I'm looking at Query Performance Insight for my read-replica database. But the information it shows are the performance stats from the primary database. How can I get the performance stats for the read-replica?


The query store for read-replicas is in preview. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/query-store-for-secondary-replicas?view=sql-server-ver16

Cool! Thank you for that reference.

This link refers to SQL Server, not Azure SQL Database.

Query Store is not available on read replicas. One way to monitor query performance is using Dynamic Management Views (DMVs).
You can rely sys.[dm_db_wait_stats] to monitor waits see script I shared on StackOverflow.
Another example of monitoring using DMVs is running this query on each replica.
SELECT 
  s.*,
  t.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) as t
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) as p -- If you wants plans also
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND s.last_execution_time >= CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETUTCDATE()) AS DATETIME) -- last 30 mins
ORDER BY s.last_execution_time DESC;

This PowerShell script was written by a Microsoft Scalation Engineer.
Azure Database Watcher is a tool that can help you monitor you Azure SQL replicas also and it is at this time in Preview.

Thanks! That select query, from where does it pull its data? From the master database on the replica server, I guess? Because the database itself is read-only, a bit-for-bit copy of the primary, correct?

DMVs can be executed on the read-only replica in contrast with Query Store that does require a read-write database. You are welcome.
